# Is there a way to make a stratified random sampler with tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a stratified random sampler with [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) for imbalanced classes but I can't find a way to do it.

```
import tensorflow as tf

dogs = [f'dog_{i}' for i in range(2000)]
cats = [f'cat_{i}' for i in range(100)]
monkeys = [f'monkey_{i}' for i in range(500)]

dogs_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dogs) 
cats_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(cats) 
monkeys_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(monkeys)
```

Maybe with `.concatenate()`? Or `.interleave()`? `.concatenate()` and `.shuffle()`?

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself. It's possible to use [`tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets), which takes a list of datasets and randomly selects from them.

For a finite dataset (that doesn't iterate inifinitely), you can repeat the minority datasets so they have approximately equal number of values than the majority category. Then, sample weights should be equal for 3 categories, so `0.33333` each.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import Counter

dogs = [f'dog_{i}' for i in range(2000)]
cats = [f'cat_{i}' for i in range(100)]
monkeys = [f'monkey_{i}' for i in range(500)]

dogs_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dogs) 
cats_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(cats).repeat(20)
monkeys_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(monkeys).repeat(4) 

all_ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(
    [dogs_ds, cats_ds, monkeys_ds], weights=[.33, .33, .33])

c = Counter()
for elem in all_ds.take(1000):
    category, _ = tf.strings.split(elem, '_')
    c.update([category.numpy()])
```

```
Counter({b'monkey': 363, b'dog': 329, b'cat': 308})
```