# Is there any method in Tensorflow to uniform split every category in a dataset into train and validation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have created an dataset with image and its label. Now I want a validation dataset. I'm worried that randomly segmenting dataset will cause some categories to appear only in the training dataset, or only in the validation dataset. Is there any method in tensorflow that can divide each category of the dataset evenly?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an easy way using Tensorflow, however, there is a more common way which is the `train_test_split` function in `sklearn`. If you want to split the dataset evenly, you should set the `stratify` parameter to your labels. You can read more about it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make a stratified random sampler with tf.data.Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229726/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-stratified-random-sampler-with-tf-data-dataset)